# Why do I have two of most default apps showing up in my app drawer?

Tags: 18.10, default, 19.04

After updating to 19.04 I noticed that some apps like calculator and files now have two versions, one with the 18.10 look and another with the new look, what should I do to get rid of the older one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty sure you have two versions of these apps installed, a "regular" version from the Ubuntu software archives, and a "snap" version.

In previous versions, these apps would be listed two times. In 19.04, only the snap version is listed in Software. This, it is not a simple matter of removing the one you do not want from Software. If you want to remove the "snap" version, you can just remove it using Ubuntu software. If, however, you want to remove the "regular" version, which in current installs is not anymore the default version, you will need to use the command line or Synaptic package manager.

For your information, the terminal commands to remove for instance Calculator are the following for the regular version and for the snap version:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-calculator
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
```

With respect to "looks": snaps do not always integrate well with your desktop theme. It might be that the one that looks "best" is the "apt" version. Just remove one, and see how the other one looks. If you want the other, remove the one you still have also, and install the other. To install, use `install` rather than `remove` in the above commands.

Comment: Do you know the name for the file browser that i can use to uninstall?

Comment: There is no file browser with which you can uninstall. If not listed in "Software", you need a package manager like Synaptic.